# WAN IP Ranges and NAT

Tags: networking, firewall, routing, wide-area-network

Let's say we have a router with a WAN IP assigned by DHCP: `1.1.1.1/255.255.255.255`

The ISP subnet for it's lan interface is `82.5.167.161/255.255.255.248`

My firewall behind this router is on WAN IP: `82.5.167.162/255.255.255.248`

I setup a one-to-one NAT for a web server on IP: `82.5.167.163`

How when an external user access the web server on the IP mentioned, does the router know to send the traffic to the firewall?

Comment: Sounds like you have your network laid out incorrectly... it hurt my eyes to read this question.  Were these supposed to be example IP addresses?

Comment: They are indeed examples.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified explanation: The ISP routes traffic for the 82.5.167.160 network to the router, the router is connected to the 82.5.167.160 network on it's LAN interface so it accepts this traffic, it knows that the firewall is also connected to the 82.5.167.160 network (on it's WAN interface), it therefore routes traffic for the 82.5.167.160 network to the firewall, which NAT's it to the appropriate internal host.

As seen in the following pics, the router is directly connected to two networks and the routing table shows routes for those two networks and shows them as directly connected, so a router does and will have routes in it's routing table for networks it is directly connected to.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joe, I understand that, my query is how it knows that 82.5.167.163 exists on that firewall, given there is nothing in the routing to tell it so and the firewall itself doesn't have an interface specifically configured on the .163 address.

Comment: Sure there is. The router knows that it is directly connected to the 82.5.167.160 network on it's LAN interface and routes all traffic for the 82.5.167.160 network out that interface to the firewall. If you were to look in the router's routing table you would see a directly connected route for the 82.5.167.160 network for the router's LAN interface.

Comment: In your example, your network is 82.5.167.160 through 82.5.167.167.

Comment: Thanks joe, the explanation is much appreciated. One final query - what if the subnet provided is shared on both the WAN and LAN. Say as above, but on the WAN of the router 82.5.167.161/255.255.255.255, the LAN interface of the router then has 82.5.167.161/255.255.255.248. Would you need to add static routes on the router to send additional IPs in that range to t he IP of the firewall? There would be some confusion here for the router surely !

Comment: This is confusing - with the above comment, would you need routes, surely as you mentioned if the subnet exists on the LAN interface it will just route it out that interface?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Because the LAN interface is in that subnet then the router will route traffic for that network out the LAN interface. Routers have routes for directly attached networks. The router is directly attached to the 82.5.167.160 network on it's LAN interface. See the pics I added to my answer for clarification.

Comment: Does this apply even when the wan interface has the same IP as the LAN interface but just in different subnets? Would you need to configure anything additional?